# jQuery overriding hyperlinks on table's td values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table as below and am trying to open a pop-up window with the link `'/ledesInvoiceErrors.do?InvoiceId='+parentInstanceId'` when user clicks on Invoice number columns of table (`INV1` and `INV2`) instead of going to the hyper link associated with invoice number fields.

http://jsfiddle.net/pmgguwob/3/

```
<div class="listTable expanded">
  <table class="searchResults {id:321}">
     <thead>
        <tr class="tipAdded">
           <th class="first unsortable ui-state-default ui-state-hover ui-state-active"></th>
           <th data-name="Invoice Number" class="typeString    ui-state-default ui-state-hover sort asc ui-state-active" id="sort_invoiceNumber">
              Invoice Number
           </th>
           <th data-name="Invoice Total" class="typeMoney last   ui-state-default ui-state-hover ui-state-active sort" id="sort_invoiceTotal">
              Invoice Total
           </th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody class="">
        <tr class="tipAdded">
           <td class="first">
              <div style="display:none" class="renderedValue">
                 INV1
              </div>
               <input value="65" name="invoices0.id" type="hidden" class="check"/>
           </td>
           <td class="typeString  ">
              <div class="data typeString"><a tooltip="" class="listLink " title="" href="/CP/show.do?parentInstanceId=51;parentFieldName=invoices">
                 INV1        
                 </a>
              </div>
           </td>
           <td class="typeMoney  ">
              <div class="data typeMoney">
                 15.25 USD        
              </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tipAdded">
           <td class="first">
              <div style="display:none" class="renderedValue">
                 INV2
              </div>
               <input value="66" name="invoices1.id" type="hidden" class="check"/>
           </td>

           <td class="typeString  ">
              <div class="data typeString"><a tooltip="" class="listLink " title="" href="/CP/show.do?parentInstanceId=55;parentFieldName=invoices">
                 INV2        
                 </a>
              </div>
           </td>
           <td class="typeMoney  ">
              <div class="data typeMoney">
                 111.25 USD        
              </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
```

Am a very beginner of jQuery and I dont really know how to achieve this. Could anyone please me with this?

Note: I dont have liberty of modifying the hyperlinks associated with Invoice number fields since these links are generated from our internal framework. but I can embed jquery script on my page to override the hyperlinks

SOLUTION UPDATED
http://jsfiddle.net/pmgguwob/10/

Comment: In our <a> tag, you need 'target="_blank" '.

Comment: @ovaherenow if I add 'target="_blank" ' in <a> tag and clicks on Invoice  number fields it doesnt goto `'/ledesInvoiceErrors.do?InvoiceId='+parentInstanceId'` URL right

Comment: Does the url work when you don't popup a window?

Comment: @ovaherenow Yes it does work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override your hyperlink's behaviour, you can do something along the lines of:

```
$(function(){
    // you may have to narrow down the selector here to a specific class or 'td'
    $(".searchResults a").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();                    
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        window.open(url, 'window name', 'window settings');
        return false;
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmgguwob/8/)**

Comment: I like the `$(".searchResults a")` suggestion so you're not grenading every `a` tag even more. ;^)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, something like this ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmgguwob/9/)):

```
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var mills = (new Date).getTime();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"), mills);
    //$("body").append("#" + $(this).attr("href") + "#");
});
```

I'm using `mills` to give each window a new handle, so you don't reuse a window and potentially confuse your user by reloading a window that's hidden from them. The last line is just to show the URL it's using for testing; you might want to massage that value a little, but I believe it's right as is.

I know [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) isn't new and cool, but [its options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position_and_size_features) let you control the new window's appearance with likely enough granularity. You could jQuery that up instead if you wanted.

Comment: I like the use of `mills`